# Different ways to specify options for select

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have difficulties to understand how `ng-model` works in select directive in angular.js. Here is the markup:

```
<h1>using ngOptions</h1>
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="value for value in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]"></select>

<h1>using ngRepeat</h1>
<select ng-model="selected">
    <option ng-repeat="value in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]" value={{value}}>{{value}}</option>
</select>

<h1>using copy paste</h1>
<select ng-model="selected">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>

<h1>Direct value</h1>
<input type="number" ng-model="selected"/>
```

`Select` with ngOptions and copy-pasted one works as expected. But `select` with ng-repeat is very different. You can test them here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gorsky/NSkz4/9/)

PS. I know that recommended way to use select is to use ngOptions. But why it misbehaves ?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the different behavior is because unlike options 1 & 3, in option 2 `ng-repeat` is creating a scope for each option.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you should use `ng-options` instead of having an `<option>` and `ng-repeat` is that Angular needs to create bindings between the `<select>` and the `<option>`s. When you create the options yourself with `ng-repeat` Angular won't know that it should set up the needed bindings to the select list.

Comment: +1 and note that ng-repeat + option doesn't work at all in IE8 (at least)